# How to get the creation time and last DDL time for role and profile objects in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am working currently on a DDL extraction script and was wondering how to get the creation time and last DDL time for some non schema objects specifically roles and profiles. For schema objects I can query the data dictionary view "DBA_OBJECTS" and use columns "CREATED" and "LAST_DDL_TIME". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeking can be achieved by using the Audit trail tables in Oracle such as the `SYS.AUD$` or the `dba_audit_trail` (if audit trail is enabled).

To get the Last DDL i.e. `ALTER USER...` for a DB user you can use something like this-

```
select a.* from sys.aud$ a, dba_users b
where a.action# = 43   --corresponds to ALTER USER
 and a.OBJ$NAME = b.username;
```

To get when user was created-

```
select a.* from sys.aud$ a, dba_users b
where a.action# = 51  --corresponds to CREATE USER 
 and a.OBJ$NAME = b.username;
```

The `dba_audit_trail` is more self explanatory. A query like below will give you a whole bunch of information including who executed the action, timestamp, the hostname etc.

```
--For DB users
select * From dba_audit_trail
 where action_name like '%ALTER USER%'
  or action_name like '%CREATE USER%';`

--For DB Profiles
select * From dba_audit_trail
 where action_name like '%ALTER PROFILE%'
  or action_name like '%CREATE PROFILE%';`
```

The above query can be modified to join with `dba_users` for DB users and with `dba_profiles` for DB profiles, with the `obj_name` column in the audit table. But be wary of the time that it may take for the query to run depending on the size of your database, number of users, and number of db profiles.

Comment: Additional info regarding the activation of auditing, you have to specify every user that is going to be audited and all actions that are going to be audited for those users ( for example option PROFILE to get actions of ALTER PROFILE, CREATE PROFILE and DROP PROFILE). Auditing can be enabled with the AUDIT statement and disabled with the NOAUDIT statement. Note : SYS user cannot be audited in the same way as other users and doing so would result in a "ORA-00983: cannot audit or noaudit SYS user actions"